# how to get child elements for specific node XML with linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i need to get all activities for claim id = "0000526_INS012_5367676737" the below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Header>
    <SenderID>INS012</SenderID>
    <ReceiverID>F-0000526</ReceiverID>
    <TransactionDate>04/11/2014 01:07</TransactionDate>
    <RecordCount>1</RecordCount>
    <DispositionFlag>PRODUCTION</DispositionFlag>
  </Header>
  <Claim>
    <ID>DHA-F-0000526_INS012_20141007135247</ID>
    <IDPayer>16175815</IDPayer>
    <ProviderID>F-0000526</ProviderID>
    <Encounter>
      <FacilityID>DHA-F-0000526</FacilityID>
    </Encounter>
    <Activity>
      <ID>779972</ID>
      <Start>07/10/2014 13:53</Start>
      <Type>5</Type>
    </Activity>
    <Activity>
      <ID>779973</ID>
      <Start>07/10/2014 13:53</Start>
      <Type>5</Type>
    </Activity>
    </Claim>
  <Claim>
    <ID>0000526_INS012_5367676737</ID>
    <IDPayer>16175815</IDPayer>
    <ProviderID>F-0000526</ProviderID>
    <Encounter>
      <FacilityID>DHA-F-0000526</FacilityID>
    </Encounter>
    <Activity>
      <ID>6767</ID>
      <Start>07/10/2014 13:53</Start>
      <Type>5</Type>
    </Activity>
    <Activity>
      <ID>67467</ID>
      <Start>07/10/2014 13:53</Start>
      <Type>5</Type>
    </Activity>
    </Claim>
</Remittance.Advice>
```

i tried to do below code , but its not working

```
  var oooo = Doc.Descendants("Claim").Where(claim => claim.Element("ID").ToString() == ClaimList.CLAIM_ID)
                                                            .SelectMany(claim => claim.Elements("Activity"));
```

Comment: define "not working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.ToString()` will return the XML of the element, including its tags.

You need to use a `(string)` cast or the `.Value` property (I recommend the former because `.Value` will throw a `NullReferenceException` if the element is not present):

```
var oooo = Doc.Descendants("Claim")
              .Where(claim => (string)claim.Element("ID") == ClaimList.CLAIM_ID)
              .SelectMany(claim => claim.Elements("Activity"))
              .Select(activity => new {
                   ID = (string)activity.Element("ID"),
                   Start = (string)activity.Element("Start"),
                   Type = (string)activity.Element("Type")
               });;
```

Comment: out of curiosity - is your use of `(string)XElement` instead of `XElement.Value` a matter of preference?

Comment: its working fine with your solution , but how can i add them to new object like  var oooo = Doc.Descendants("Claim")
              .Where(claim => (string)claim.Element("ID") == ClaimList.CLAIM_ID)
              .SelectMany(claim => claim.Elements("Activity")) .select new ??

Comment: @decPL There's a practical reason for it. If there are any `Claim` elements without an `ID` child element, then `claim.Element("ID").Value` will throw a `NullReferenceException`, whereas `(string)claim.Element("ID")` will simply be `null` and the `Claim` element will be skipped. The `(string)` cast is more fault-tolerant.

Comment: @JLRishe guess I'm getting too used to C# 6.0 with `?.`; that was a daft question, disregard

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"YourXMLFile.xml");
var result = xdoc.Root.Descendants("Claim")
                 .Where(x => x.Element("ID").Value == "0000526_INS012_5367676737")
                             .Select(x => x.Descendants("Activity")
                                          .Select(z => new
                                          {
                                             ID = z.Element("ID").Value,
                                             Start = z.Element("Start").Value,
                                             Type = z.Element("Type").Value
                                           }).ToList());
```